# E/MediaProvider: Writing to a non-default top level directory is not allowed

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello i am creating a photo editor app in which when user select and crops the image it will be saved in /photoeditor/.crop for further editing the app will get the cropped image from the folder and will be set as image in editor activity

but the application is unable to create folder /photoeditor/.crop if it does not exist and if i manually create folder even then the cropped image is not saving in this folder

Logcat

```
2021-07-16 05:03:38.349 1389-4569/com.google.android.providers.media.module E/MediaProvider: Writing to a non-default top level directory is not allowed!
```

code for creating and saving in directory

```
public static String getDirPath() {
String dirPath = "";
File imageDir = null;
File extStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
if (extStorageDir.canWrite()) {
  imageDir = new File(extStorageDir.getPath() + "/photoeditor/.crop");

}
if (imageDir != null) {
  if (!imageDir.exists()) {
    imageDir.mkdirs();
  }
  if (imageDir.canWrite()) {
    dirPath = imageDir.getPath();
  }
}
return dirPath;
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `context.getExternalFilesDir("photoeditor" )` ? If your app has a targetSdk 29 or 30 it means that you need to stop using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` because it is gonna be deprecated.